# Conflict with selecting data from MS Access database using C# Form

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I am using microsoft visual studio community 2017.
My database is from MS Access (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0)
I think my query is conflicting when chkNum.
These are my sample select query, 4 total.

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

if (frmTopic.chkRndQ == true && frmTopic.chkNum == false)
{
    chkQ = true;
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP " + numR + " QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER,CONTENT FROM " + tab + " WHERE CONTENT IN ('" + top + "') ORDER BY RND(-(1000*ID)*Time())";
    remain = frmTopic.randNo;
    num = numR;
}

if (frmTopic.chkRndQ == false && frmTopic.chkNum == false)
{
    chkQ = false;
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP " + numR + " QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER,CONTENT FROM " + tab + " WHERE CONTENT IN ('" + top + "')";
    remain = frmTopic.randNo;
    num = numR;
}

if (frmTopic.chkRndQ == true && frmTopic.chkNum == true)
{
    chkQ = true;
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP " + numX + " QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER,CONTENT,NUM FROM " + tab + " WHERE CONTENT IN ('" + top + "') AND NUM BETWEEN " + num1 + " AND " + num2 + " ORDER BY RND(-(1000*ID)*Time())";
    remain = frmTopic.no;
    num = numX;
}

if (frmTopic.chkRndQ == false && frmTopic.chkNum == true)
{
    chkQ = false;
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP " + numX + " QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER,CONTENT,NUM FROM " + tab + " WHERE CONTENT IN ('" + top + "') AND NUM BETWEEN " + num1 + " AND " + num2 + "";
    remain = frmTopic.no;
    num = numX;
}

OleDbDataAdapter dAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
dTable = new DataTable();
dAdap.Fill(dTable);
currentRow = 0;
lblNo.Text = currentNo.ToString();
nextRow();
connection.Close();
```

When I run the program, the query should select the numR or numX data depending on the conditions.

If I choose to check chkNum, input num1 and num2. The problem is, if I choose to uncheck chkNum, it will only query the previous numX data instead of numR data. But it will query correctly if I checked again the chkNum and input num1 and num2, or if I just leave chkNum unchecked.

The difference with chkNum is that it will only select a specified n data from ONE content inside the table. If it is unchecked it will randomly select a specified n data from more than ONE content inside the table.

Comment: @june7: I am impressed with your 4 gold badges - but try not to hunt for badges - they come when they come. If you edit a post by just altering the white-space and eliminating a typo you work towards your badges and not the goal of helping others. On the contrary: the post gets your name and credentials on the frontpage and thus signals a difficult but also thought through question instead of a newbies that could also be very easy to answer...

Comment: I am not 'hunting' badges, I simply wanted to make the narrative easier to read. If I stumble over some grammar/punctuation, I expect someone else would as well. It's so easy to do a quick edit.

Comment: but do you know what seems bugging with my query?

Comment: You are using top as name of a variable. TOP has special meaning in SQL statement, suggest you use something else as variable name. Why use IN if the content of `top` is just a string? Otherwise, issue may be with C# logic. Don't see variables (top, numR, numX) declared and set.

Comment: @June7, my top is declared like this top = string.Join("','", list); it will join the strings that are checked in the checklist. Also top is declared private static string. numR and numX is declared as private static int since their value will are set on a different form.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, think I was just tired when I wrote that.